# select union all order by

Tags: sql-server, union-all

```
SELECT TOP 1
        hol_id ,
        CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), hol_date, 112)
FROM    holiday
WHERE   hol_id = 5
UNION ALL
SELECT  hol_id ,
        CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), hol_date, 112)
FROM    holiday
WHERE   hol_id <> 5
ORDER BY CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), hol_date, 112) DESC
```

I see

```
1   20131218
5   20131018
6   20130818
3   20130405
4   20130311
2   20121129
```

I want to see

```
5   20131018
1   20131218
6   20130818
3   20130405
4   20130311
2   20121129
```

Comment: Can you explain that order you want to see? The dates aren't in chronological order e.g. hol_id 1 is 2013-12-18 which is after the dates for hol_id 5 (2013-10-18) and hol_id 6 (2013-08-18), but you want it to be ordered between them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be ordering by actual date (`hol_date`) not by converted varchar value.

Assuming `hol_id` *as* `Key column` of the table (Not sure why you are using a TOP 1 here), try this query with `ORDER BY CASE` as below:

```
SELECT  hol_id ,
        CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), hol_date, 112)
FROM    holiday
ORDER BY CASE WHEN hol_id = 5 
              THEN DATEADD(year,100,getdate()) --Assuming 100 years as max
              ELSE hol_date 
         END DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

I would compute a new value to move a particular record to the top, as in:

```
order by
      case when hol_id = 5 then 0 else 1 end -- Sort hol_id 5 at the top
    , hol_date desc -- Sort the rest according to date
```